# Plotting contours for geodetic data.(in Python)

Tags: contour, matplotlib

I need to plot contour plot for a geodetic dataset, but I have data for 15 locations of New Zealand. I have been able to generate a map a New Zealand using cartopy library of Python, but I am not sure how to get the contour plot, since the 'countourf' function of matplotlib takes in a grid of longitudes and latitudes of the whole concerned area, along with the data at each grid-point. but I only have data for few(15) specific locations.

Comment: You may use algorithms of QGIS or GRASS GIS to generate a GRID from your points (TIN, IDW, RST interpolations). These can be used from Python or you can use the GUI. Having so few points, I suppose TIN or RST would give better result.

Comment: With so few points spanning all of New Zealand can you expect the contours to have much meaning?

Comment: I am actually taking a small area of New zealand into consideration